# Spring OAuth2 provider with Email & Google Sign In

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth, authorization

> I have developed a Spring server that serves an Android app where
>   **users can sign up via email or via Google**. Sign up in this case is performed via grant type `password` / `google`.

Now, I am planning to let my server act as a **OAuth2 provider** where users can connect external clients and hand access tokens to them via `authorization_code` grant type allowing these clients to access certain REST API endpoints on my server.

The basic flow is like this:

1. On the external client, the user initiates a call to `/oauth/authorize` endpoint with parameters

   - response_type : code
   - client_id : id_of_client
   - redirect_uri : uri_where_external_client_can_receive_auth_code
2. custom design login page is shown, user enters username and password
3. after successful login, user is presented with the "confirm access" page (`/oauth/confirm_access`) and grants access to the client
4. after confirmation, the redirect uri is called with a `code` parameter usable for getting tokens
5. external client calls the `/oauth/token` end point with parameters

   - grant_type : authorization_code
   - code : auth_code_that_was_previously_returned
   - client_id : id_of_client
   - redirect_uri : ...
6. upon success, access & refresh token are returned

> I have already implemented this flow, and it works.

Now I want to ramp things up a little bit and enhance my custom login page with the ability that users can not only authenticate via username and password to connect external clients, but also via Google.

The problem is that my login form currently looks like this (custom_login.jsp):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="/login" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="password"
                    class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>

            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, submitting the login form makes a POST request to the `/login` endpoint of my server which is out of my control and redirects to the `/oauth/confirm_access` endpoint.

If I want to support Google sign in I would have to add a Google sign in button to my custom_login.jsp and then I am pretty much stuck. **I have no idea how I can validate the user that signed in with Google** with my server like the `/login` endpoint does with username and password and then further redirect to `/oauth/confirm_access` endpoint. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Can you use Google provided OAuth2 token to authenticate user at your server, no?

Comment: Yes, I can do that from my android app by calling `/oauth/token` with grant type "google" and a google id token.

Comment: Sorry, still did not understand clearly, but here is my try: on your `custom_login.jsp` have `Google Sign In` button, and let google redirect user after successful authentication to `http://your_server/app/login_with_google` API with token, and after that each request to your server will contain that token as Bearer header..